# Mass Update Data Extension Names

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

Is there a way I can mass update Data Extension names? I have a ton of them which I need to rename. Can SSJS or any API call be used?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the [WSProxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_update.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, best done with SSJS and [WSProxy Update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_update.htm). This example retrieves the DE Customer Keys then uses that to update the Name. I tested using a Cloudpage, but depending on the number of DEs you need to update, it may be better to use a Script Activity in Automation Studio.

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core","1.1.5");
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();    

    var des = ['DEName0','DEName1','DEName2'];

    for (var i=0; i<des.length; i++) {
        var filter = {
            Property: "Name",
            SimpleOperator: "equals",
            Value: des[i]
        };
        // Retrieve DE Customer Keys
        var data = prox.retrieve("DataExtension", ["CustomerKey"], filter);
        Write("<br>DE key: " + data.Results[0].CustomerKey);
        var de = {
            CustomerKey: data.Results[0].CustomerKey,
            Name: 'NewDEName' + i
        };
        //Update DE Name
        var resp = prox.updateItem("DataExtension", de);
        Write("<br>Response: " + resp.Results[0].StatusMessage);
    }
</script>
```